how i can speed up my view query in oracle sql 11g database
i created the 3 separate view and then join the three views and create forth one now my forth view is very slow when i query it how i can speed up this view am mentioning my forth view
SELECT
A.PR_ID,
A.ORDER_NO ,
A.PR_DATE,
A.INVDETAILCODE,
inv_code_validation(A.INVDETAILCODE) ITEM,
NVL(A.COLOR_ID,0) COLOR_ID,
NVL(COLOR_ID_VALIDATION(A.COLOR_ID),'NA') COLOR,
NVL(A.ITEM_SIZE_ID,0) ITEM_SIZE_ID,
NVL(size_id_validation(A.ITEM_SIZE_ID),'NA') ITEM_SIZE,
NVL(A.GSM,0) GSM,
NVL(A.WIDTH,0) WIDTH,
NVL(A.THICKNESS,0) THICKNESS,
A.UOM,
A.QTY,NVL(B.UNIT_ID,0) UNIT_ID,
B.PO_ID,
NVL(B.PO_DOCNO,'NA') PO_DOCNO,
NVL(B.PO_SR_NO,0) PO_SR_NO,
NVL(B.PO_DATE,SYSDATE) PO_DATE,
NVL(B.PO_TARGET_DATE,SYSDATE) PO_TARGET_DATE,
NVL(B.APPROVED_QTY,0) PO_QTY,
NVL(C.MDOC_ID,0) GRN_PKEY,
NVL(C.DOC_ID,0) GRN_NO,
NVL(C.DOC_DATE,SYSDATE) GRN_DATE,
NVL(B.PARTY,'NA') PARTY,
NVL(C.PURCHASE_INV_NO,'NA') PURCHASE_INV_NO,
NVL(C.PURCHASE_INV_DATE,SYSDATE) PURCHASE_INV_DATE,
NVL(C.BAL_QTY,0) RCVD_QTY,
NVL(GET_REM_PO_SR_MARKET_QTY(B.PO_SR_NO),0) PO_BAL,
GET_IGP_FROM_PO(B.PO_ID) IGP_NO,
NVL(C.REJ_QTY,0) REJ_QTY,

NVL(B.NET_UNIT_PRICE,0) NET_UNIT_PRICE



FROM V_PR_PO_GRN_TRACKING_REQ A,V_PR_PO_GRN_TRACKING_PO B,V_PR_PO_GRN_TRACKING_GRN C
WHERE A.REFE=B.REFE
AND b.REFE=c.REFE
AND A.ORDER_NO='0-16'
ORDER BY A.PR_ID;


Please clarify your specific problem or provide additional details to highlight exactly what you need. As it's currently written, it's hard to tell exactly what you're asking.
